# Ambiguous use of 'init' swift 4

Tags: swift

I'm try to do a test programing while I coding I saw this message

> Ambiguous use of 'init'

and this is the code

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var numberField: UITextField!


@IBAction func Click(_ sender: Any) {


    if let old = numberField.text {

        if let oldAsNumber = Int(old) {

            let oldIncatYears = oldAsNumber * 7



            label.text = "you are " + String{oldIncatYears} + " years old"


        }
    }
}
```

I hope you can help me fix it

Comment: Use () to call an initialiser/method and not {}. This is a very basic thing that you should know about a language.

Comment: Don't add irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
String{oldIncatYears}
```

use

```
String(oldIncatYears)
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because you are not initialising string object properly.
use it :

```
label.text = "you are " + String(oldIncatYears) + " years old"
```